# What calibration options should I look into given these defects

Tags: calibration

I printed a temperature calibration cuboid for Hatchbox 1.75 mm PLA, in 1 °C increments from 180 °C to 190 °C.

I have two questions related to this image:

[image: Temperature calibration print]

- I'm not seeing any difference in quality across the temperature range. Am I just way off base and need to be substantially higher?
- How do I get rid of the small layer shifts you can see across the board?

Printed on a RepRapGuru Prusa MK2 clone.

Comment: Most slicers/printers use Celsius and not Fahrenheit for temps. If you are running things in F (Fahrenheit), you're running your temps way too low. You should be running PLA around 200 **°C**. At 180 °F, this is ~82 °C ... I'm betting you mean you are extruding at 180 °C ... still, this is pretty low, even for PLA. I'd suggest running your temps from 195 °C to 210 °C and checking the difference.

Comment: Woops. Yes, typo - C, not F.

Comment: Even so, 180-190 is usually pretty low for print temps using PLA ... just a thought.

Comment: Fair. I was under the impression that you want to go as low as you can without extrusion issues. Is that not the case? And will this address the unevenness I'm seeing?

Comment: Couldn't what you are seeing be considered extrusion issues? Try it, as what do you have to lose but a little time and filament.

Comment: Sure. I'm referring to what looks like unevenness or layers along the corners of the print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your print does **not** suffer from layer shifts as you call them. This uneven layer deposition is typically caused by the (positioning) accuracy of your printer. All-in-all, this print does not look so bad. You would get better quality prints on a different style of a printer; most high-end printers have a lowering platform instead  of a forth and back moving platform.

Although 180 °C is at the low side of printing PLA (usually it starts at about 185 °C), the print does look okay. However, looks can deceive, it does not say anything about structural integrity (layer bonding).

Note, to calibrate the temperature using a temperature tower, you need a different calibration test print, preferably one that tests overhang. This latter is usually far more important as there is normally not much to see at the walls, you need a slanting part in the print or an overhang to determine the optimal temperature.